# dired-dwim-target for frames?

Tags: dired, frames

I exclusively use frames and I've long wondered if there's a way to get `dired-dwim-target` to suggest a dired buffer from another frame instead of just another window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redefine `dired-dwim-target-directory` so that in the call to `get-window-with-predicate` it passes a non-nil value (e.g., `visible`) for optional arg `ALL-FRAMES`:

```el
(defun dired-dwim-target-directory ()
  ;; Try to guess which target directory the user may want.
  ;; If there is a dired buffer displayed in one of the next windows,
  ;; use its current subdir, else use current subdir of this dired buffer.
  (let ((this-dir (and (eq major-mode 'dired-mode)
               (dired-current-directory))))
    ;; non-dired buffer may want to profit from this function, e.g. vm-uudecode
    (if dired-dwim-target
    (let* ((other-win (get-window-with-predicate
                       (lambda (window)
                         (with-current-buffer (window-buffer window)
                           (eq major-mode 'dired-mode)))
                         nil
                         'visible)) ; <========================
           (other-dir (and other-win
                           (with-current-buffer (window-buffer other-win)
                             (and (eq major-mode 'dired-mode)
                                  (dired-current-directory))))))
      (or other-dir this-dir))
      this-dir)))
```

And please consider filing an enhancement request (`M-x report-emacs-bug`), suggesting, for example, that this argument be taken from the value of `pop-up-frames` (or from a new user option or from something else). The idea is to let users decide whether the Dired buffer is to be in another window of the same frame or in any (visible) frame.

---

**UPDATE**

I've added this to [**Dired+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) ([`dired+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el)), so it should work out-of-the-box.  It respects a new Boolean option, **`diredp-dwim-any-frame-flag`**: non-nil means look also in other frames.  The default value is the value of `pop-up-frames` (so if that option is non-nil then so is `diredp-dwim-any-frame-flag`).

Comment: A gentleman and scholar. Thank you!

Comment: Still, please consider filing an enhancement request for vanilla Emacs. Emacs developers tend to overlook the use cases of "exclusively using frames". That's understandable, I guess, but it doesn't mean that improvements to handle such use cases are not desirable. ;-)